# Http Client that allows 50 threads to call a host concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x

Based on a requirement to call an external service which could be accessed by 50 threads concurrently I have designed a simple POC below

```
public class ExternalServiceHelper {
    private static RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(60 * 1000)
            .setSocketTimeout(60 * 1000).build();

    private static CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().
        setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).
        useSystemProperties().
        setMaxConnTotal(50).
        setMaxConnPerRoute(30).
        build();

    public  String sendToExternalService(HttpPost httppost) throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpResponse response =null;
        response=closeableHttpClient.execute(httppost);
        String reponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println(reponse);
        httppost.releaseConnection();
        response.close();
        closeableHttpClient.close();
        return response;
    }
}
```

The method sendToExternalService might be called upto 50 concurrent threads from a Rest Api Service Layer. i.e

/api - 50 users might be calling the api concurrently and from the service layer I need to make a call to the external service using sendToExternalService. I create a new Instance of ExternalServiceHelper from the service layer and then call the sendToExternalService with different HttpPost request.

Here I have kept the CloseableHttpClient static so there is only One copy and resuing the CloseableHttpClient from the pool as I have set MaxConnPerRoute and MaxConnTotal using the builder.

Will this have any synchronization issues, like thread 1 getting a response of a different thread?

Answer (score 0):

[CloseableHttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html) is declared with [ThreadingBehavior SAFE](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/current/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/annotation/ThreadingBehavior.html#SAFE)

> Instances of classes with the given contract are expected to be fully thread-safe.

```
@Contract(threading=SAFE)
public abstract class CloseableHttpClient
extends Object
implements HttpClient, Closeable
```

Also, `client.execute(request)` has been [deprecated](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/CloseableHttpClient.html#execute-org.apache.hc.core5.http.ClassicHttpRequest-).

Answer (score 0):

For multithreading use cases there is no need to make CloseableHttpClient singleton, that client usually has configured a HttpConnectionManager, for example an instance of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager, which controls creating, leasing/reusing and termination of HTTP connections and is perfectly suited to serve many HTTP requests coming from concurrent threads.